# Execute decorators runs forever for sonar with mysql database

Tags: sonarqube

In our setup the sonar and the database are both running in the same machine. But our sonar analysis is hanged forever when we are running from jenkins. We get the below output

> [INFO] [11:54:14.200] Execute decorators... [DEBUG] [12:03:38.232]
>   Decorator time:   ManualMeasureDecorator: 209936ms
>     SumDuplicationsDecorator: 84ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator@2f46a8: 302236ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.core.security.ApplyProjectRolesDecorator@1c7f922:
>   9ms   org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.DirectoriesDecorator@1a53786: 21ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator@1e0684a: 16ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TimeMachineConfigurationPersister@170a9c8:
>   1414ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageFileAnalyzer@1deede8:
>   10ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewItCoverageFileAnalyzer@d52ab0:
>   3ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewOverallCoverageFileAnalyzer@e5bc87:
>   6ms   org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageAggregator@bc77d7:
>   18ms  org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ClassesDecorator@19a9cac: 20ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionsDecorator@1a3e41a: 11ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.ProjectDsmDecorator@d4837f: 7ms
>     FileTangleIndexDecorator: 11ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.SuspectLcom4DensityDecorator@1e4308c:
>   13ms  f(lines): 11ms  f(generated_lines): 27ms    f(ncloc): 3ms
>     f(generated_ncloc): 6ms     f(classes): 10ms    f(packages): 9ms
>     f(functions): 16ms  f(accessors): 13ms  f(statements): 11ms
>     f(public_api): 7ms  f(comment_lines): 6ms   f(comment_blank_lines):
>   7ms   f(public_undocumented_api): 10ms    f(commented_out_code_lines):
>   7ms   f(complexity): 9ms  f(complexity_in_classes): 11ms
>     f(complexity_in_functions): 7ms     f(class_complexity_distribution):
>   15ms  f(lines_to_cover): 5ms  f(uncovered_lines): 12ms
>     f(conditions_to_cover): 6ms     f(uncovered_conditions): 6ms
>     f(it_lines_to_cover): 13ms  f(it_uncovered_lines): 8ms
>     f(it_conditions_to_cover): 4ms  f(it_uncovered_conditions): 9ms
>     f(overall_lines_to_cover): 3ms  f(overall_uncovered_lines): 6ms
>     f(overall_conditions_to_cover): 17ms
>     f(overall_uncovered_conditions): 5ms    f(rfc): 22ms    f(lcom4): 18ms
>     f(package_cycles): 7ms  f(package_tangles): 6ms
>     f(package_feedback_edges): 9ms  f(package_edges_weight): 13ms
>     f(new_lines_to_cover): 6ms  f(new_uncovered_lines): 5ms
>     f(new_conditions_to_cover): 8ms     f(new_uncovered_conditions): 6ms
>     f(new_it_lines_to_cover): 3ms   f(new_it_uncovered_lines): 14ms
>     f(new_it_conditions_to_cover): 6ms  f(new_it_uncovered_conditions):
>   8ms   f(new_overall_lines_to_cover): 9ms
>     f(new_overall_uncovered_lines): 7ms
>     f(new_overall_conditions_to_cover): 10ms
>     f(new_overall_uncovered_conditions): 7ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.cpd.decorators.DuplicationDensityDecorator@27bee9:
>   35ms  CountUnresolvedIssuesDecorator: 987ms
>     CountFalsePositivesDecorator: 133ms     CommentDensityDecorator: 60ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ChidamberKemererDistributionBuilder@1600021:
>   11ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FileComplexityDistributionDecorator@1a8773b:
>   26ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionComplexityDistributionBuilder@12be637:
>   59ms  PackageTangleIndexDecorator: 8ms    f(file_complexity): 31ms
>     f(class_complexity): 27ms   f(function_complexity): 16ms
>     f(function_complexity_distribution): 101ms
>     f(file_complexity_distribution): 37ms   f(rfc_distribution): 10ms
>     f(lcom4_distribution): 6ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.WeightedIssuesDecorator@10fb346: 91ms
>     IssuesDensityDecorator: 46ms
>     org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TendencyDecorator@68347b: 46098ms
>     VariationDecorator: 39ms
>
> [DEBUG] [12:03:38.233] 24761 measures to dump [DEBUG] [12:03:46.964]
>   Updating semaphore batch-com.pnmr.PNMRProject:PNMRProject-project
>   [DEBUG] [12:03:58.084] Updating semaphore
>   batch-com.pnmr.PNMRProject:PNMRProject-project

We are using sonar version as 3.7. Please suggest any workaround.

Comment: When the batch is frozen, could you have a look on MySQL side to see any possible pending/locked SQL requests ?